# Is there a way to make objects in typescript valid only when their props are being used?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say that I have an api that always returns text objects as this

```
interface Content {
  Content_Type: string;
  Text: string;
}
```

There are various objects that conform to this structure, and there is never a case where I'd want to work with the object other than presentationally.

In React, I can do the following without any typescript errors, however, I *will* get a React error saying that objects cannot be used as React children. `<p>{Claim_Text}</p>`

Is there a rule which I can specify to be something like

> This object can never be used on its own, it must be one of its props

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with that? Print object value as string? You can stringify the object if that helps.

var obj = { name: 'Tarik', lastname: 'Neradin'};

JSON.stringify(obj);

"{\"name\":\"Tarik\",\"lastname\":\"Neradin\"}"

Comment: Make the interface private or otherwise unavailable to the view, and read the properties into top-level fields in your view model?